# Change column ordering from mobile to desktop layouts

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implement below designs using grid layout:

[image: mobile][image: desktop]

This is what i tried but not what i wanted.

http://jsfiddle.net/tomalex0/3fesK/3/

```
<div>
   <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3 row-one">1</div> 
   <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9 row-two">2</div>
   <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3 row-three">3</div>
</div>
```

I don't want to use absolute to make it work, as the footer comes under the absolute div.

Please let me know if its possible.

Comment: usually when viewing on portable devices only the width of the column is adjusted,along with some other modifications of course but here I can see that you have re-arranged the divs completely. Are you sure this is what you want? Bootatrap wouldn't support it directly

Comment: I was trying to avoid multiple 2's, but if its not possible i  will go with multiple 2's by hiding and showing based on form factor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 pull-right">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 pull-left">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-9 pull-right">3</div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/28RsL/

Comment: Probably much better than my way. +1

Comment: I've had to do your method in a few cases, but I don't think it's necessary here.

Comment: was about to comment on the redundancy of declaring .col-xs-12, then tested it to be sure, and saw it's NOT redundant when pulls are in place. somehow the pull kills the default col-xs-12. I'm a little befuddled by this - can shed any light as to why?

Comment: Off the top of my head, `.pull-*` adds a float, which makes the element inline-block but doesn't explicitly set width (or sets it auto).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/zSf8uqdoQq) demonstrating most of your solution. You will need to include cases for other viewports to make this work on all of them, but most of it is done for you. What I did was make multiple containers named `2` to build the desktop layout, and hide it for the mobile layout and vice versa.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 hidden-sm">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">2</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">1</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 hidden-lg">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">2</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 col-md-offset-4 col-sm-12">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">3</h3>

            </div>
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image]

[image]