# Change section order with Bootstrap 3

Tags: css, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

On a page I have two columns. On the first one (black), I have one section which contains an image. The second one, has two blocks (blue and green).

I want to change the order of the three sections like in this schema I have made:

[image: screenshot]

I found some way of doing with push and pull, but it's only put the black block last instead of first.

Comment: Post some relevant code and we can help you! Why not just keep all of this inside of one column? Are you wanting this to change on resize?

Comment: Is the left picture desktop size, and the right mobile?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change column ordering from mobile to desktop layouts](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787646/change-column-ordering-from-mobile-to-desktop-layouts)

Comment: @JordanD : Yes, its to desktop at left and mobile at right.

Comment: @BuddhistBeast : I will post some code tomorrow, it's at work now(i'm an intern)

Comment: @KyleMit : you're righr, in my search, I've not found this answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adapted from [Isherwood's answer in this very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24788626/1366033):

Have them in order on a small screen, and then on a larger screen, pull them to the appropriate side of the page:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 blue pull-right"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 black pull-left"></div>
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 green pull-right"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/NDN7W/)

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Pretty much exact same format as this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24787646/change-column-ordering-from-mobile-to-desktop-layouts/

Comment: @JordanD, Yes!  Thank you.  I thought I was going crazy.  I remembered the solution and thought it was very clever and I've been looking for the post so I could attribute / close as duplicate.

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer. I'm now aware that a answer already exist, but I didn't find before posting this answer. I will try to be more effective in my future search. I will try soon as possible. When I will try, and I'm pretty sure thqt will work, I will accept this answer.