# Bootstrap 3 | three columns 3rd collapses under 1st in smaller screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, layout, multiple-columns

I am trying the whole morning to solve this one. It looks obvious but somehow I can't make it work.

I am using Bootstrap 3 and I want to have this effect with a 3 column layout

**On wide screens**
3 column layout
1 - 2 - 3

**On narrow screens**
3rd column collapses under the first column to create a two column layout like:

1 | 2
3 | 2

At this point my 3rd column always stacks after the seconds column height!

**On phones**
1
2
3

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: You have four columns or three? You should post a fiddle or bin. People don't want to freely answer you and create all the html required to do this. Start with mobile first in your html, start to add the push and pull classes and the grid column classes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Th column widths will all work fine with a regular set of classes like this:

```
class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4"
```

It's just a matter of targeting `sm` sized screens to appropriately clear the content.  Based off my answer to [Change section order with Bootstrap 3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24872884/1366033), you could do something like this:

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">1</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4 middleDiv">2</div>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-4">3</div>
</div>
```

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 991px) { 
    .middleDiv {
       float: right;
    }
}
```

### [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/NDN7W/10)

[image: screenshot]